# String formatted as UTF-8 in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, utf-8, ascii

I'm reading from a CSV file with columns of various types.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
df.head()[columnname]
```

```
0    b'Hi,\r\n\r\nI hope you are well.'
1    b"\xc2\xa0Hello,\r\n\xc2\xa0\r\n "
2    b"\r\n\r\n blah blah blah"
3    NaN
4    b'blah blah blah'
Name: columnname, dtype: object
```

From my understanding, the `b''` format implies that it is a byte string and I have to `.decode('utf-8')` it to a string formatted in ascii and remove `b''` as well as encodings like  `\xc2\xa0`. However, when I try to decode, I get an error.

```
df[columnname] = df[columnname].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
```

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I think what is going on is that when reading from the csv file, the column is set to `str` data type, as such `"b'Hi...'"`. So I checked the raw CSV file, and I saw `previous_column,"b'Hi....'", next_column`. Is there a way to properly read this column as a byte string such that I could later call the decode function?

I've also tried setting the `dtype=np.bytes_`for that specific column in the `pd.read_csv()` function and calling `df.astype` after reading the csv, but neither works. My last resort would be to manually remove the encodings with regex.

Comment: Can you show us the CSV (or a small part of it) for test? It seems like that column is the string representation of a python `bytes` object. Is that what's supposed to be in that column? Its kinda an odd thing to have in a CSV, but maybe that is the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column values are really strings like this: `"b'some string'"`, then you can try apply `ast.literal_eval` on them:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].fillna("b''").apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x).decode('utf-8'))
print(df)
```

Should print:

```
   index                       columnname
0      1  Hi,\r\n\r\nI hope you are well.
1      2                 Hello,\r\n \r\n 
2      3          \r\n\r\n blah blah blah
3      4                                 
4      5                   blah blah blah
```